# Page php to find a file in a network filesystem

Tags: php, file, filesystems, share

I would like know a function that when i have a path and a piece of filename, the php page find into a directory and give me a result true or false.

For example on the `explore.exe` i search `%99999%.pdf` and i have a result. I want replicate the same thing in a php page.

I've find on the internet the function file_exist but i don't know how i pass the `%9999%` tipe.

`$a=file_exist('mydirectory\%999999%.pdf');` doesn't work.

The `r/w` permissions are guaranteed.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Comment: right but where i place the directory on the glob function?

Comment: I don't know what you're asking.

Comment: i've 4 directory for example, how can i specify in which directory i would find my file with glob funcion?

Comment: array glob ( string $pattern [, int $flags = 0 ] ) but ther isn't a directory slot into a function

Comment: Put the directory in the glob...?  Research glob a bit more.  You can do `directory/*999999*.pdf` as the glob.